# How to simulate a delta hedged option strategy

Tags: options, monte-carlo, delta-hedging, option-strategies, delta

I'd like to do a montecarlo simulation of a $\Delta$ hedged strategy (long OTM call) to see how the PnL distributes on cases like:

- $\sigma_{bought} < \sigma_{realized}$
- $\sigma_{bought} > \sigma_{realized}$
- $\sigma_{bought} = \sigma_{realized}$.

For this, I calculate the purchased option price with $\sigma_{bought}$ at $t_0$ and then do a random walk for the underlying asset $S$ so I can modify the hedge amount on each step.

My problem is that in order to calculate the hedge amount variations on $t$, I do not only need a new $S_t$ but also a volatility as $\Delta$ depends on vol (at least with BSM formula:  $N(d_1)$ where $d_1$ depends on vol).

**Question:** What volatility should I use on each step to calculate the new $\Delta$ of the option?

Comment: The simplest, but still interesting, case: at time 0 you (and everyone else) believe that the vol will be $\sigma_b$ so this is how the option is priced **and** how you will calculate $\Delta$ for hedging. But from 0 to T the actual movements of the stock are controlled by $\sigma_r$ (and you don't know this).

Comment: So, for example If I want to compare $\sigma_b = 10\%$ with $\sigma_r = 15\%$. That means I should calculate initial option value with $\sigma = 10\%$, but then on each step: montecarlo simulation as well as $d1 (for \Delta)$ will use $\sigma = 15\%$?

Comment: See below "Calculate initial option value with vol(b) = .10, and the hedging delta at each step with vol(b) = .10. But then use vol (r) = .15 to calculate the path of the stock."

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with nbbo2. I did this exact thing a while back.

[So, for example If I want to compare =10% with =15%. That means I should calculate initial option value with =10%, but then on each step: montecarlo simulation as well as 1(Δ) will use =15%?]

Calculate initial option value with vol(b) = .10, and the hedging delta at each step with vol(b) = .10. But then use vol (r) = .15 to calculate the path of the stock.

[image: Monte Carlo Excel]